# Слайдер не работает в IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Здравствуйте . Слайдер не работает в IE . Сайт doovad.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в jQuery 2.х отказались от поддержки допотопных браузеров, таких как IE8. [пруф](http://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Answer (score 0):

Какой слайдер? В какой версии IE? В каком окружении? Что значит "не работает"? Ты думаешь сейчас все кинутся смотреть твой сайт и накручивать тебе посещаемость? Создай отдельную страницу, размести там слайдер, распиши что именно не так и кинь ссылку сюда, можно будет разобраться.

Comment: для чего мне это накручивать если сайт еще тест версия? Просто не понимаю в чем проблема в новой версии нету проблем а в 8 проблема . В Firefox, chrome, opera все окей. @Get

Comment: Используй jquery 1.9